# How to start reading quantum computing papers?

Tags: resource-request, nielsen-and-chuang

What's the best way to get to a state where you can read quantum computing papers? I find them too dense and full of notation to approach.

I am currently working my way through Nielsen and Chuang's book. How much time should I give myself to get through the book? Is there anything I can be doing or some papers that are more easily accessible right away?

Comment: I read [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee384m/Handouts/HowtoReadPaper.pdf) paper about reading papers a while ago and found it helpful, maybe you'll find it helpful too